# Do the cursors used in pagination have a specific lifespan or timeout?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, pagination

In the documentation on [pagination](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/) there is a section about using cursors to check for new content. This implies that you can store the cursor and come back later to see if something new has appeared. Do the cursors timeout at some point or have a specific lifespan? If I get a cursor while paging through the comments on a post, will that cursor still be valid after an hour, a day, or even a week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentaiton, it will be always valid.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/

"Cursor pagination is our preferred method of paging, and the list of Graph API endpoints which support it are growing. A cursor refers to a random string of characters which mark a specific point in a list of data. You can reliably assume that a cursor will always point to that same part of the list and use it to page through the data.

If you are using additional filters on the API endpoint when you receive a cursor, this cursor will only work for calls with those filters."

**Update**

As pointed by [Scutterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989477/scutterman), these cursors also have a lifespan. You should discard it after 1 day.
"Pagination markers used in these methods should not be used in long-lived applications as a way to jump back into a stream. For example, storing the cursors in a database and then re-using them a few days later may return stale, incorrect, or no data at all. Make sure that your cursors are relatively fresh - less than a day at most."

Update:
At some point the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/) added the information point:

```
Don't store cursors. Cursors can quickly become invalid if items are added or deleted.
```

Comment: I guess I didn't read the word "always" in that section previously.

Comment: At the bottom of that page linked, it also states `Pagination markers used in these methods should not be used in long-lived applications as a way to jump back into a stream.` because the data may become stale

Answer (score 2):

There is a note in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#paging):

> Cursors can't be stored for long periods of time and expected to still work. They are meant to paginate through the result set in a short period of time.